# How to manage setting file in WebStorm using VCS?

Tags: intellij-idea, webstorm

I have several computers... like you. home desktop, mac, office desktop, etc.

Each of computer installed WebStorm IDEA, I want to share my idea setting file every computers.

I found **Exporting setting file** menu on WebStorm, which makes `settings.jar` file.

Okay, If I import this `settings.jar` file from another computer, it will be a way of it.

But my settings file updated very often. so above way little bit inconvenient, I want to simply manage it with VCS, How can I do that??

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please consider using the [Settings Repository](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.3/sharing-your-ide-settings.html) plug-in. It does exactly what you need.

Answer (score 1):

You just check in most of the project files.
Here is a good description: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544839

For us it worked fine as long as all developers use the same IDEA version. When versions differ it might lead to "settings ping pong" where each version stores the project settings a little differently and so they keep changing.

Comment: I think @Juntae was asking about IDE settings, not the project settings.